# SQLAlchemy: Как отсортировать по func.count в one-to-many relationship?

Tags: sql, python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Последнее время столкнулся с этой проблемой, так как нехочу заводить лишние поля в таблицах для количества того или иного контента, помогите плз, я Flask начал изучать недели 3 назад.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Если я Вас правильно понял...

Сортировку в relationship можно задавать при помощи аргумента order_by (http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html).
т.к. Вам необходимо сортировать по func.count, то Вам нужно использовать подзапрос.

```
class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column('id', BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    name = Column('name', String)
    parent_id = Column('parent_id', BigInteger, ForeignKey('parent.id'))

class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column('id', BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    name = Column('name', String)
    children = relationship(Child, order_by=lambda:select([func.count(text("*"))]).select_from(Child).as_scalar())
```

Вместо `select([func.count(text("*"))]).select_from(Child)` используйте нужный Вам подзапрос.

Если я Вас понял неправильно, опишите, пожалуйста, задачу более подробно, предоставив исходники и пример запроса на SQL, который Вы хотите.